# NDSolve returns a copy of itself

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a differential equation like:

```
NDSolve[{F w[x]/EI == w''[x]/(1 + w'[x]^2)^(3/2), w'[0] == 0, w[0.01/2] == 0} /. {EI -> 0.00012, F -> 0.01}, w, {x, 0, 0.01/2}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {w[0] == 0.08}}]
```

However, it just returns a copy of itself without any error information.

I have tried some other initial points:

```
Map[First[NDSolve[{F w[x]/EI == w''[x]/(1 + w'[x]^2)^(3/2), w'[0] == 0, w[0.01/2] == 0} /. {EI -> 0.00012, F -> 0.01}, w, {x, 0, 0.01/2}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {w[0] == #}}]] &, Range[0, 0.1, 0.01]]
```

A few of them work well.

Please help~

Following @bmf suggestion.

The equation describes the bending deformation of a slender beam. The
bending moment equals `F w[x]` where `w[x]` is the deflection of the beam. `w''[x]/(1 + w'[x]^2)^(3/2)` is the curvature of the beam, and `EI` is the bending stiffness. As we compress a slender beam, `w[x]==0` is definitely a solution, but when the beam bends a little, I think there is another equilibrium state.

It's a buckling problem. Detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_critical_load

When I changed the curvature expression as @Ulrich suggested, everything just worked!

But still, I don't understand why `NDSolve` would return an unevaluated result without any error information in some conditions.

Comment: A solution to your ODE is `w[x] = 0`, and I do not believe that there are any others for the boundary conditions specified.  Perhaps, this is why the "Shooting" `Method` is causing problems.

Comment: Actually, I realize that nobody welcomed you here properly. Better late than never, so...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @ddwell ok, thanks for the feedback, but I don't want to spam the comments section below the suggested answer. I see there's some confusion. can you back to your post and describe the D.E with mathematical equations? you can leave the code as it is, just write down the D.E and the conditions in TeX form please

Comment: Check the expression for the curvature! It should be `w''[x]/(1 + w'[x]^2)^(3/2)` I think

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I got it! You're right!

Comment: @ddwell You try to solve Euler buckling case #3?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yeah, case 2. I want to calculate the deflection after buckling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value for L is missing, once assigned then it can be solved without any problem.

```
L = 1;
NDSolve[{F w[x]/EI == w''[x]/(1 + w'[x])^(3/2), w[0] == 0.08, 
   w[L/2] == 0} /. {EI -> 0.00012, F -> 0.01}, w, {x, 0, L/2}]
Plot[w[x] /. %, {x, 0, L/2}]
```

[image]

It seems there isn't a meaning solution for `w'[0]=0`, to explore it further we can use the 'ParametricNDSolveValue' to look for a nontrival solution. For this I have used the condition `w'[0]=w0`, where 'w0' is in the interval `[-1,1]`.

```
L = 0.01;
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{F w[x]/EI == w''[x]/(1 + w'[x])^(3/2), 
    w'[0] == w0, w[L/2] == 0} /. {EI -> 0.00012, F -> 0.01}, w, {x, 0, L/2}, {w0}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[sol[w0][x], {w0, -1, 1, .1}]], {x, 0, L/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**After OP's correction**

```
    L = 0.01;
    sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{F w[x]/EI == w''[x]/(1 + w'[x]^2)^(3/2),
         w'[0] == w0, w[L/2] == 0} /. {EI -> 0.00012, F -> 0.01}, 
      w, {x, 0, L/2}, {w0}]
Plot[Evaluate[sol[0][x]], {x, 0, L/2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can't call this an "unevaluated result" becasue `NDSolve` produces an ouput with that particular set of conditions but the solution seems to be trivial.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have correct L. Please review it

Comment: @ddwell Just change the value of L in my response.

Comment: In my case `L = 0.01`(as I have corrected in my question), and it doesn't work.

Comment: @ddwell I think the approach that zhk is suggesting in this answer works and this is why I upvoted. There seems to be a typo in the answer `w'[0] == 0`. Perhaps there was some confusion with the edits in the OP or something. I am attaching a [**`screenshot`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8bIK.png) to show that it works nicely.

Comment: @bmf But, my initial condition is exactly `w'[x]==0`, and my assumpted initial condition for shooting is `w[x]==0.08`. Therefore the result @zhk gave is wrong (sorry, I mean no offense).

Comment: @ddwell the approach that they suggested is correct, though, as it can be seen from the screenshot. I just adopted their approach and fixed some typos. Do you agree with that?

Comment: @bmf There is another boundary condition, `w[L/2]==0`. I don't understand why you change it. Is there any suggestion? Many thanks~

Comment: @ddwell for 2nd order you only need two conditions

Comment: @zhk yeah, two of my conditions are `w'[0]==0, w[L/2]==0`. I'm not sure if there is any suggestion. Many thanks~

Comment: @ddwell from where you get the condition w(0)=0.08?

Comment: @zhk, `w[0]==0.08` is an assumpted initial condition for the shooting method.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer~ Does it mean `NDSolve` would return an unevaluated result when Mathematica "thinks" there is no solution?

Comment: @ddwell see the updated version...

Comment: @ddwell if you could share the background of this equation then we will be able to understand more? Any link?